# matplotlib.image "file not found" error when running

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have been working on trying to get my python program and I need to use matplotlib for image processing.
I've been having a lot of trouble but I followed all the examples that I can find online. I had a hard time getting matplotlib to install.

Image of Errors
[image]

Second image of errors
[image]

tried:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as aImage

```
img = 'Alabama.jpg'
img_Alabama = plt.imread(img)
plt.imshow(img_Alabama)
```

&

```
img_Alabama = plt.imread('StepOne\MatLibPhotos\Alabama.jpg')
plt.imshow(img_Alabama)
```

Comment: Did you use pip install? Also we can't help you unless you tell us what your problem is

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In order for people to help you you will need to edit your question and offer more details, chiefly what code you are using. You can put code inside a code block surrounded by three backticks ( ` )  on each end.

Comment: I added a image of the problem.

Comment: File "C:\Users\a_sid\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2904, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Alabama.jpg'

Comment: I've changed the directory locations of the image and copied path. All seem to be getting the same error

Comment: Maybe I am need to format the path differently?

Comment: I did the pip install matplotlib, it says the requirements are already met

Comment: error is quite descriptive itself. It can not find the file name `Alabama.jpg`. It looks like your `path` is wrong. try `img_Alabama = plt.imread('MatLibPhotos\Alabama.jpg'); plt.imshow(img_Alabama)`

Comment: Still saying the same error. ive tried { '\Desktop\Py startpoint\StepOne\MatLibPhotos\Logo-Test.png'} which is a different photo and file type.   File "C:\Users\a_sid\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\PIL\ImageFile.py", line 109, in __init__
    self.fp = open(fp, "rb") FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\\Desktop\\Py startpoint\\StepOne\\MatLibPhotos\\Logo-Test.png'

Comment: I have I feeling that maybe its python needs to be deleted and reinstall from the ground up